# JavaScript: Splitting multiple space character string with a space character returns an array with 2 blank characters

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to split a string by space character (`\s`) in JavaScript. But when I provide a string having multiple space characters, it returns an array with 2 blank characters. Below is my code:

```
let s = "                 ";
console.log(s.split(/\s+/));
```

This is the output:

```
►(2) ["", ""]
```

Can anybody please explain, what is happening here?

Comment: \s is for any whitespace chars so it will treat following spaces as one. If you only care about space char then use split(/ /) instead.

Comment: I'm curious what you _expect_ to happen and also what result you are _hoping_ to get?

Answer (score 1):

**\s+** will not split the string by each space character but by limitless sequences of space characters. I mean, every sequence of spaces will be considered as a single separator. For example:

```
let s = "asd           fgh jkl";
console.log(s.split(/\s+/));
>> (3) ["asd", "fgh", "jkl"]
```

When you split, even an emtpy string will return an array with a single empty element while the needle is not empty.

```
let s = "";
console.log(s.split(/\s+/));
>> (1) [""]

let s = "";
console.log(s.split(/a/));
>> (1) [""]

let s = "";
console.log(s.split(" "));
>> (1) [""]
```

If the needle **happens to be at the start or at the end of the string**, the string is still being partially splitted and an empty element is pushed. It happens with any kind of characters (not just whitespaces). Check these examples:

```
let s = " a ";
console.log(s.split(/\s+/));
>> (3) ["", "a", ""]

let s = "aaaaaaaaaa";
console.log(s.split(/\a+/));
>> (2) ["", ""]

let s = "a a";
console.log(s.split(/\a+/));
>> (3) ["", " ", ""]
```

Returning two empty elements from a non-empty string consisting of just whitespaces is just a consequence of that, since the whitespace sequence is starting and ending the string:

```
let s = " ";
console.log(s.split(""));
>> (2) ["", ""]

let s = "          ";
console.log(s.split(/\s+/));
>> (2) ["", ""]
```

If you want to return an empty string, consider filtering the empty elements in the resulting array:

```
let s = "          ";
console.log(s.split(/\s+/).filter(b => b != ''));
>> []
```

or simply

```
let s = "          ";
console.log(s.split(/\s+/).filter(b => b));
>> []
```

The empty array will be returned only if the needle is empty:

```
let s = "";
console.log(s.split(/()/));
>> []

let s = "";
console.log(s.split(""));
>> []
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `\s+` will match 1 or more space characters in a row and SPLIT the string when it finds a match. Your string contains 1 or more space characters, so it will remove those characters and SPLIT the string into 2 halves. With one half being the part of the string before the match, and the other being the part of the string behind the match. In your case, both of those parts end up having no characters in them. However the split function doesn't care, it found the space characters it was looking for, so it did it's job and SPLIT the string.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you're using, `\s+`, matches any non-zero number of "space" characters, and the entirety of the string assigned to the variable `s` matches that regular expression. Thus the entirety of `s` splits its left-end, `""`, from its right-end, `""`.